# How to add file name to syslog string?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing an embedded application in C in Linux user-space.
I need to add the file name and function name to syslog string.
how can i do that ?

note: to better explain my self, i need to define a macro that fills in the file name and func name..
what i did was the follwing:

```
#define LOG(prio, ...) my_log(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, prio, __VA_ARGS__)
```

and the problem is in the implementation of my_log:

```
void my_log(const char *file, int line, const char *func, int prio, const char *fmt, ...)
{
//how to add the "filename:line, funcname: " string to the fmt string
va_start(args, full_fmt);
vsyslog(prio, full_fmt, args);
va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: what about formatting a string including the names and send it to syslog? If you want to ask a good question you should include what you've done and why do you think what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`syslog` accepts a `printf` like format string. You are probably referring to something along the lines of:

```
syslog(1, "%s:%d: something bad happened", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

`__FILE__` automatically expands to a string containing the current source file. `__LINE__` similarly expands to the current line in the current file.

Comment: if using this multiple times, do make sure your embedded systems compiler doesn't leave a separate copy of the `__FILE__` string constant within the binary for each time its used

Comment: @Alnitak, do you know any compiler that does?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but nor (AFAIK) do the standards mandate that they shouldn't.